Expand/Resize a div with JavaScript Touch Events


function touchEvtResize() {
    var block = document.getElementsByClassName("top-three-quarters"),
        slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");

    slider.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        let dragY = e.clientY;

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
            block.style.height = block.offsetHeight + e.clientY - dragY + "px";
            dragY = e.clientY;
        });

        docuemnt.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) { });
    });
}
.top-three-quarters {
    overflow-y: auto;
    resize: vertical;
}

.bottom-quarter {
    flex: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 5%;
}

.slider {
    background-color: #dee2e6;
    cursor: row-resize;
    user-select: none;
    height: 10px;
}
<div class="top-three-quarters">
</div>
<div class="bottom-quarter">
  <div class="slider">
  </div>
</div>



I have this code which works with mouse events. But I would like to make it work with touch events for touchscreens. I have been doing research and have not been able to find anything helpful. I am still new with JS so any guidance is helpful. Preferably no libraries if possible. I have a fiddle of what it looks like with mouse events.
<div class="top-three-quarters">
</div>
<div class="bottom-quarter">
  <div class="slider">
  </div>
</div>

.top-three-quarters {
    overflow-y: auto;
    resize: vertical;
}

.bottom-quarter {
    flex: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 5%;
}

.slider {
    background-color: #dee2e6;
    cursor: row-resize;
    user-select: none;
    height: 10px;
}

    let block = document.querySelector(".top-three-quarters"),
        slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

    slider.onmousedown = function dragMouseDown(e) {
        let dragX = e.clientY;

        document.onmousemove = function onMouseMove(e) {
            block.style.height = block.offsetHeight + e.clientY - dragX + "px";
            dragX = e.clientY;
        }

        document.onmouseup = () => document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;

    }

Fiddle
I have tried similar examples such as Example1 and example2 but no luck. Not asking you guys to code it for me but just some guidance and tips so I can solve it!

Have you read up about touch events? You'll need to decide which ones you'd like to correspond to the mouse events.

@AHaworth I tried adding the addEventListener('touchstart', function(e))  to replace the mouse events as well as touchmove but no luck.

Please show the code you have tried, preferably as a runnable snippet (<> in the editor).

@AHaworth I added the way I tried it with touch events that did not work out for me.

I was able to make it work with some blazor. I just did the function in c# and passed the event from blazor to js to avoid touch events in javascript.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
